# How do I remove the orange exclamation mark warning on kfmclient_html.desktop icon

Tags: linux, file, debian, desktop

In the directory folder for my desktop I see a file named 'kfmclient_html.desktop' that does not show on my actual desktop. It's icon is the same as konqueror and it has an orange warning exclamation point on it. It is an executable and it says that it was created around the time when installed this linux distro on my machine and i believe its says the date it was last modified is before the date I installed it. I'm not sure what this file is for but I assume that it is not good that there is a warning on it. How do I remove the warning?

I tried executing the file but it said that I didn't have permission and to send a bug report. I considered reinstalling the package but I am not sure which package exactly to reinstall.